# If $T^2=O$ where $O$ is $O(\vec{x})=\vec{0}$, prove that $T$ has no inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $T: X \to X$. If $T^2=O$ where $O$ is $O(\vec{x})=\vec{0}$ $\forall \vec{x} \in X$, prove that $T$ has no inverse.

**Attempt**

We could use the fact that if $T$ has an inverse, the dimension of its domain and range must be the same. If we suppose this is true, then the range of $T$ is $X$. Then, for any $\vec{x} \in X$ there is an $\vec{x}' \in X$ such that $T(\vec{x}') = \vec{x}$. For any $\vec{x} \neq \vec{0}$, we could apply this twice to see
$$
\vec{x} = T(\vec{x}') = T(T(\vec{x}'')).
$$
But since $\vec{x}$ is non-zero, we have reached the contradiction $T^2 \neq O$. This proves the statement.

Is this a valid attempt? Are there better ways to prove this?

Comment: There is a much straightforward proof sing the fact that the product of invertible maps is invertible. Suppose by contradiction that $T$ is invertible, then $0=T^2$ is invertible as well: a contradiction.

Comment: I haven't learned that yet. I would probably need to prove it first but that's good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct and uses the fact that if $T$ were invertible, it must be onto. You can run a similar argument with the assumption that $T$ is one-to-one:

If $T$ would have an inverse, it would be in particular one-to-one. Since $T(T(x)) = 0$ for all $x \in X$ we would then have $T(x) = 0$ for all $x \in X$ which in particular implies that $T$ is not one-to-one (unless $X$ is zero dimensional).

Comment: Thanks. You've confirm my attempt and provided an answer of your own using a different approach. This is exactly what I was looking for so I will accept your answer.